# Extract code of svg element from aspx page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, svg, telerik

I currently have an aspx page that contains a Telerik component which is going to be rendered as an SVG file, basically if I launch the page in IE and right-click and save, I can save the RadHtmlChart as an svg. What I want to do is to do this automically in a codebehind and save the string of that svg file into an variable so it is in memory without launching. This is what I have right now but it is not working.

Aspx code (EDITED:)

```
               <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

            <%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

            <!DOCTYPE html>

            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head runat="server">
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <form id="form1" runat="server">
                           <telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
                               <Scripts>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                                   <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js">
                                   </asp:ScriptReference>
                               </Scripts>
                           </telerik:RadScriptManager>
                           <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                           </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                           <telerik:RadHtmlChart runat="server" ID="RadHtmlChart1">
                                <Legend>
                                    <Appearance Position="Bottom">
                                        <TextStyle FontSize="14" Color="Blue" FontFamily="Courier New, sans-serif" />
                                    </Appearance>
                                </Legend>
                                <PlotArea>
                                    <XAxis>
                                        <Items>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41872"/>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41873"/>
                                            <telerik:AxisItem LabelText="KM41871"/>
                                        </Items>
                                        <MajorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                    </XAxis>
                                    <YAxis>
                                        <MinorGridLines Visible="false" />
                                    </YAxis>
                                    <Series>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Mean">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.6" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.64" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.65" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.67" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.63" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Min">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.56" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.57" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.59" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.61" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.55" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                        <telerik:LineSeries Name="Max">
                                            <SeriesItems>
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.66" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.72" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.73" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.74" />
                                                <telerik:CategorySeriesItem Y="0.71" />
                                            </SeriesItems>
                                        </telerik:LineSeries>
                                    </Series>
                                </PlotArea>
                            </telerik:RadHtmlChart>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenVariable" runat="server" />
                </form>
            </body>
                <script>
                    var RadHtmlChart1 = $find('<%=RadHtmlChart1.ClientID %>');
                    var svg = RadHtmlChart1.getSVGString()
                    document.getElementById("hiddenVariable").value = svg;
                </script>
            </html>
```

codebehind code:

```
Public Class WebForm1
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim html As String = hiddenVariable.Value.ToString
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You can get the svg string in javascript, would that work?

Comment: could you show me how? I think javascript should work. I am willing to give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will let you get the chart's svg on the client side.

```
<script>
    var RadHtmlChart1 = $find('<%=RadHtmlChart1.ClientID %>');
    var svg = RadHtmlChart1.getSVGString()

</script>
```

Source: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-client-side-api.html

Comment: I am not really familiar with javascript, is there anyway I can extract the string from the svg variable back to the codebehind code of vb?

Comment: You could pass it back to the server via web-service.

Comment: I tried passing it back using a hidden control but there and it appears there is no code in the svg variable

Comment: Putting it in a hidden variable should work. Could you update the question with the latest version of the code?

Comment: I've added the new code and also the codebehind code

Comment: In the Page_Load code, are we posting the page back anywhere before checking that variable? There would have to be a button or something needed to trigger a postback. When you mentioned the svg variable is empty did you set a breakpoint on it/check in the console?

Comment: yep, I added a breakpoint and the variable is empty. I am not too sure about posting back, the hidden variable was something i found online where people said it is a good way to pass variables back from javascript to vb.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57038/discussion-between-andrew-walters-and-batman-in-disguise).

Comment: andrew, please check my last line in chat

Answer (score 0):

1) RadHtmlChart renders only in the browser, with JavaScript, so to get its SVG you need to run a browser instance

2) the JS code is executed too early, look into the Sys.Application.Load event (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383829.aspx) or its pageLoad(){} shortcut. Accessing RadHtmlChart (and other such controls earlier is not possible).

3) take a look at this code library entry, it uses a button click but the logic should be similar: http://www.telerik.com/support/code-library/exporting-radhtmlchart-to-png-and-pdf.

4) consider using a tool like PhantomJS or something similar so you can run the browser on the server and get the needed data there. An automated testing tool may also help you by executing something like a recorded test in the browser you launch on the server.